# how to read org.apache.catalina.connector.request InputStream twice, using requestFacade wrapper?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to read inputstream of the request object more than once during my filter chain. How should i do this using RequestFacade wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees the input stream can be rewound.  You could call `markSupported()` and if that returns `true` then `mark()` before you start reading and `reset()` to rewind it.  If `markSupported()` returns false then you'll have to buffer it yourself.

Comment: I want something like making inputstream of Request as bytearrayinputstream using wrapper class of RequestFacade. In case of Request its coyoteinputstream. i don't know how to handle this.